# Change input in a Child React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hello i have a component in react that has this usetstate

```
    const [answers, setAnswers] = useState({
        q1: '',
        q2: '',
        q4: '',
        q5: '',
        });
```

and i have an array of question :

```
{id: q1
q: "question1"
att: []
}
{id: q2
q: "question2"
att: []
}
{id: q3
q : "question3"
att: []
}
{id: q4
q: "question4"
att: []
}
{id: q5
q: "question5"
att: []
}
]
```

and i want in the parnt component to send each qestion to the child compont

```
return(questions.map((obj)=><childComponent obj = {obj}/>));
```

the problem is the if i set a input elemnt in the child component i can only put one char
and i think its because it render the parent elment each time
i try to set the value of the input with
`props.setAnswers(...answerts , [id]:event.target.value)`
but its not working
can someone can help me and give me a way to do it so i can do it and still save the values in the parent component?
thanks

Comment: use props in react https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: i know how to use props but when i update a state in the child component the parent component is re render and the input that was before is beeing deleted so the props dont help me

Comment: i don't think that will happen can you make an example on codesandbox or playcode?